# LINK-fatal error LNK1104 can't open file wxmsw29ud_xrc.lib in DialogBlocks

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, wxwidgets, fatal-error

I am new to wxWidgets and to DialogBlocks and i following instruction that were given in reference book of wxWidgets by julian smart. when i am compiling sample project as "vc++ project debug with set all the path as given i got two type of error everytime

FATAL ERROR: 1104 1083 
i am using visual studio 2010 and MINGW

following line of error

LINK-fatal error LNK1104 can't open file wxmsw29ud_xrc.lib

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to upgrade to wxWidgets 3.0.2 instead of using some old development 2.9.x version. Second, you need to build the wxWidgets libraries to ensure that they are there in the first place. Third and finally, you need to set the linker library search path to contain the directory where the libraries are.

Comment: i have done all things with 3.02 but still problems.....and i am using it with Dialogblocks....so all the library path is to be set with dialogblocks.........and i am facing same problem with codeblocks....